# TypeScript convert tuple of objects to object with keys the common property value of each object and values the actual object

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript tuple of objects where all of them have the property `name`.

```
type components = [
    {
        name: "fruit";
        color: string;
    },
    {
        name: "car";
        speed: number;
        brand: string;
    }
];
```

I want to create a helper type to which I will pass the tuple type and it will convert it to the following

```
type wanted = {
    fruit: {
        name: "fruit";
        color: string;
    },
    car: {
        name: "car";
        speed: number;
        brand: string;
    }
};
```

I tried this type

```
type tupleToObject<T extends any[]> = {
    [K in components[number]["name"]]: T[number];
};
```

So that I will then be able to do the following

```
const foo: tupleToObject<components> = {
    fruit: {
        name: "fruit",
        color: "red"
    },
    car: {
        name: "car",
        speed: 5,
        brand: "toyota"
    }
}; // typescript is ok with this assignment

const color = foo.fruit.color; // but here got error in .color
```

But `color` is underlined red and if I hover it says

```
Property 'color' does not exist on type '{ name: "fruit"; color: string; } | { name: "car"; speed: number; brand: string; }'.
  Property 'color' does not exist on type '{ name: "car"; speed: number; brand: string; }'
```

Is this achievable with TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapped type would need to look like this:

```
type TupleToObject<T extends any[]> = {
  [K in T[number] as K["name"]]: K;
}
```

We map over each element `K` of the union `T[number]` and use key remapping to extract `name` from the union element `K`.

```
const foo: TupleToObject<Components> = {
    fruit: {
        name: "fruit",
        color: "red"
    },
    car: {
        name: "car",
        speed: 5,
        brand: "toyota"
    }
}

const color = foo.fruit.color
// works fine now
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAdhFwDOUC8UDaAUFCVAN7GlUoCGCEAXFAEQBmATgK4CWwzA3JSokAxnAA2cdk0zB23FAHNBVAL4AaIeS3U6jFiJrsBO0pkgQAJkxScEAIwjsVwkvfY0U1qLPlKXJKqEALqEhKCQUAAqnGDiEFFwAPL2AFYQIsAAPFFQEAAewOiW2J4g+MEAfLjaJPgA0lAK0fi2Dk7BUDTY9fjMtPTMwcFM9YJBhGIoslCscHBMMXEJyWkZ2fBIqOhY1XgUVBw8wEwHrlAD+mxcvMya51BiktIs7FbMWhpahi9nrpdMZg-O6mEjmCBWJgAVnu53cnm8zGAcBAcGANA+akIEymMyeUhqczgADojrxifj2EA)